# WSL2 jupyter notebook cannot use kernel install in conda environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have anaconda with jupyter notebook installed in my WSL2
however, when I'm start the jupyter notebook, It not use my conda environment but using from window

[image]

In the "Change kernel" menu only Python3 is available

```
(env) user@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Users/user$ ipython kernelspec list

Available kernels:
       python3    /home/user/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
       pytorch    /home/user/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/pytorch
       rlml       /home/user/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/rlml
```

I already tried
`python -m ipykernel install --user --name env --display-name "name"`
but still doesn't work.
Is there anyway to force jupyter notebook to use kernel in WSL ?

I also tried to use from VS code itself but I face another problem.
When try to change jupyter kernel to my conda environment it prompt dialog
[image]

but after click install, it can't find

```
-bash: C:/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/env/python.exe: No such file or directory
```

I have checked the directory and it have python.exe in there.